# Get IDs and date range from add/remove group log

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, select

| project_id | group_id | added_or_removed | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | added | 2021-07-21 0:00:01 |
| 2 | 2 | added | 2021-07-21 0:00:01 |
| 3 | 1 | added | 2021-07-21 0:00:01 |
| 4 | 2 | added | 2021-07-21 0:00:01 |
| 1 | 1 | removed | 2021-07-21 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | added | 2021-07-21 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | removed | 2021-07-21 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | added | 2021-07-21 12:00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | removed | 2021-07-21 12:00:00 |
| 3 | 2 | added | 2021-07-21 12:00:00 |
| 4 | 2 | removed | 2021-07-21 12:00:00 |
| 4 | 1 | added | 2021-07-21 12:00:00 |

Consider the above data. project_id 1 and 3 moved from group_id 1 to 2 at `2021-07-21 12:00:00`. Similarly, project_id 2 and 4 moved from group_id 2 to 1 at the same time `2021-07-21 12:00:00`.

I want to get date ranges from the above data for given group_id. Eg. for input group_id 1 and input date range 2021-07-21 0:00:00 to 2021-07-21 23:59:59, I want output as below

| from | to | group_id | project_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-21 0:00:01 | 2021-07-21 11:59:59 | 1 | 1,3 |
| 2021-07-21 12:00:00 | 2021-07-21 23:59:59 | 1 | 2,4 |

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JSBach How do you think can I clarify it more? Or what is not clear?

Comment: Current data storing scheme does not provide data consistency. This must be fixed before the task solving - inconsistent data may produce the result which will be safe visually but incorrect.

Comment: @Akina I can change `added_or_removed` to boolean field. What else?

Comment: This does not prevent added after added or removed without added and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question much and according to my inference, I have prepared the following query that implements the table you want.

```
select distinct "2021-07-21 0:00:01" as "from","2021-07-21 23:59:59" as "to", (1) as group_id,Group_Concat(project_id) as project_ids 
from datatable1
where project_id in(1,3) and timestamp between '2021-07-21 0:00:01' and '2021-07-21 11:59:59'
group by group_id

union all

select distinct "2021-07-21 12:00:00" as "from","2021-07-21 23:59:59" as "to", (1) as group_id,Group_Concat(project_id) as project_ids 
from datatable1
where project_id in(2,4) and timestamp between '2021-07-21 12:00:00' and '2021-07-21 23:59:59'
group by group_id
```

deom in [*paiza.io*](https://paiza.io/projects/Q2nyK6GnBKSWp-Iszk4zxw?language=mysql)

Comment: specific output has been selected in this answer. Obviously there will not be only these 4 projects and 2 groups. Rather there will be 100s of projects and more than 2 groups at least. Also many projects can and will move from one group to another at different times.